# C# class constructors creating infinite loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So lets say I have two classes. Class A and Class B like this:

```
Class A
{
    B classB;

    public A
    {
        classB = new B();
    }

    public void funcIHaveToUseInClassB()
    {
    }
}

Class B
{
    A classA;

    public B
    {
        classA = new A();
    }

    public void funcIHaveToUseInClassA()
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see both classes contain functions that need to be used in the other class. Class A has a function that class B has to use and the other way around. No I can't just put the functions in the other class because they heavily rely on the class they are currently in. So how would I go about doing this? With my method I create an infinite loop and get a stack overflow exception. I hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
People are asking me why I need these 2 classes to rely on each other so here it is: Class A manages everything that has to do with a WebBrowser control and class B Manages everything that has to do with a certain page in my program. Class A is being used by multiple pages, which is the reason it needs to be a seperate class. Class A sometimes needs to push info to class B. Class B sometimes needs info from the WebBrowser control class A is managing and that is why it calls a function.

Comment: What is the _actual_ problem, not the problem with your proposed solution, but the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Make classB and classA into public properties and initialize them from another class instead of constructor.

Comment: The problem is that the classes keep calling each other, creating an infinite loop and crashing the program. @maccettura

Comment: @uRThow No, that's the problem *with your code*, not the problem you are trying to solve in your program.

Comment: Could you explain that further? You mean I create a class C where I initialize both A and B, and whenever A needs a function from B I call it through C? Last time I tried this it wouldn't work since it just wouldn't allow me to do this: From script A: C.B.Func(). @just-my-name

Comment: Why is that not the problem I am trying to solve? My program is crashing because of the infinite loop. That is the problem I am trying to solve. I need to be able to use both functions from every class but not have them initialize each other every time. @Adrian

Comment: @uRThow You have a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Your "solution" is not working so you are trying to get help with something that may not solve your _actual_ problem.  Stop telling us the problem with your solution, we can all very clearly see what the problem is.  Instead describe to us the problem you are _ultimately_ trying to solve

Comment: To try and clarify other comments.  There is probably a better solution that what you are trying to do.  What is the ACTUAL PURPOSE you are trying to do instead of creating class A and B relying on each other.  You don't have to expose private/confidential info, but at least clarify what you are NEED from your application.  Why does A rely on B and vice-versa.  Edit your existing question and add clarification to the bottom vs just filling in comments.

Comment: @uRThow I posted that explanation as answer

Comment: If the functions are required by more than 1 class, put them in a base class and inherit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make classB and classA into public properties and initialize them from another class instead of constructor.

```
class A
{
  public B classB { get; set; }

  public void funcIHaveToUseInClassB()
  {
  }

  public void anotherF()
  {
     classB.funcIHaveToUseInClassA();
  }
}

class B
{
   public A classA { get; set; }

   public void funcIHaveToUseInClassA() 
   {
   }

   public void anotherF()
   {
      classA.funcIHaveToUseInClassB();
   }
}


static void main()
{
    // entry point
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();
    a.classB = b;
    b.classA = a;
    // do what ever you want with a and b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an instance of one of your classes to the constructor of the other class.
Try this:

```
Class A
{
    B classB;

    public A()
    {
        classB = new B(this);
    }

    public void funcIHaveToUseInClassB()
    {
    }
}

Class B
{
    A classA;

    public B(A arg)
    {
         classA = arg;
    }

    public void funcIHaveToUseInClassA()
    {
    }
}
```

**Update**

Or just pass in the instance as a parameter to the methods like in Matt Jacobsen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a private and public accessor, and instantiate the property only when the private object is null, like so:

```
class A
{
  private B _b;
  public B b {
    get {
      if (_b == null) _b = new B();
      return _b;
    }
  }

  // Constructor can now be empty
  public A()
  {
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your reference from B/A in to A/B each time you need to use it. You don't need the constructors.

```
Class A
{
    public void funcIHaveToUseFromClassB(B classB)
    {
    }
}

Class B
{
    public void funcIHaveToUseFromClassA(A classA)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But how would I call: funcIHaveToUseFromClassA(A classA) inside of class A exactly?

Comment: all sorts of ways! You could use Properties, you could extract all the A/B functionality to a third class "C" and pass in references to A/B, you could consolidate A and B into a mega class AB, etc etc. It all depends on your situation, and you are the person in the best position to make the best decision.